# Why does AutoHotKey not execute a {Left} after the () section?

Tags: autohotkey

I want this AutoHotKey script:

```
::aaim::
(
==aim
2010

2
){Left}{Up}
```

to output this:

```
==aim
2010
|
2
```

but it outputs this instead:

```
==aim
2010

2{Left}{Up} }|
```

(where "|" is the cursor)

**How can I get it to print the first version?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
:r0*:aaim::
(
==aim
2010

2
{Left}{Up}
)
```

In action:

[image]

Comment: perfect, what does the "r0*" actually mean?

Comment: +1 for the convincing video, what tool did you use to record the .gif?

Comment: r0 stops the continuation () from using default raw mode to send text. The asterisk (*) triggers the key and it sends the text as soon as you press the `m`, so pressing space or enter afterwards isn't necessary (and would only make things harder since I'd have to add another `{Left}`).

Comment: animation was done in camtasia